# Object doesn't support property or method 'is'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have jquery script which gives matched items but it working in Firefox but not in IE, in IE it gives me **

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'is'

**
Here I am using jquery 1.9.1

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
            var $t = $(this).val();
            for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9XDQ/

Comment: var $t = $(this).val(); $t is nolonger a jquery object here.

Comment: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) - *Returns: String or Number or Array*; none of which has an `is` method

Comment: @Phil but How it works in FF, when I debug this snippet $t gives me some value.

Comment: @jerjer how can you tell $t is nolonger a jquery object, in FF it's there

Answer (score 1):

By moving from

```
var $t = $(this).val()
```

to

```
var $t = $(this);
```

things will work.  As mentioned in the comments, $(this).val() is not a jQuery object.  It's almost certainly a `String` since it's getting the `value` attribute from the DOM element.

Also, I tried your fiddle in Firefox and looking at the console, the error does trigger.  It doesn't kill the page or show any kind of alert, but the functionality of the filter is not going to work.